# Is $(x^2,xy)$ a primary ideal in $k[x,y]$ for $k$ a field?

Tags: commutative-algebra

In **Example** of Page 52 in Atiyah's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*

> $\mathfrak a = (x^2,xy)$ is not a primary ideal in $A = k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field.

I think, for any $z \in \mathfrak a$, there exists $z' \in A$ satisfying $z = xz'$. But $x^2 \in \mathfrak a$. So $\mathfrak a$ is a primary ideal by the definition on Page 50 of the same book.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of primary is not as symmetric as you seem to think.

[It says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal)

> If $ab \in I$ then $a \in I$ or $b^m \in I$ for some $m>0$.

Apply this with $a=x$ and $b=y$. It does not work. (It does work,  with $a=y$ and $b=x$, but this does not suffice.)

An equivalent definition is:

> If $ab \in I$ then $a \in I$ or $b \in I$, or *both* $a,b \in \sqrt{I}$.

Again, it does not work out for $xy$, as $x \notin \mathfrak{a}$, $y \notin \mathfrak{a}$ an $y^m \notin \mathfrak{a}$ for all $m >0$ so $y \notin \sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a misunderstanding of the definition. I thought the condition was: for any $z \in I$, there were $a,b \in A$ satisfying $z =ab$, $a \in I$ or $b^m \in I$ for $m>0$. In fact it is: for any $z \in I$ and any $a,b \in A$, if $z = ab$, then $a \in I$ or $b^m =I$ for $m>0$.

Comment: You are welcome. I see. Note that the existential form you assume would not be so interesting as you always have $z =  z \cdot 1$.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly is not primary, since this would mean that, in the quotient ring $k[x,y]/I$, zero divisors are nilpotent. However, $y$ is clearly a zero-divisor, but it is not nilpotent, since it would imply that, in the factorial ring $k[x,y]$, some power of $y$ is divisible by $x$.